# how to draw dot's along with the texture movement using libgdx in android

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a ball which will be thrown by user.Now i want to draw some texture along the path in   which the ball was travelling. I have tried by saving the ball's positional vector and drawn   another texture along that path.But,as the render continuously gets called the texture is   getting disappeared.I want to save the entire path of the ball and want to draw another   texture along that path as we see in angry birds. When the user throws the bird, a path will   be displayed until the next throw.

Comment: how is the ball moving? using actions, or by physics?

Comment: @Ludevik, using physics(box2d in libgdx)

Comment: @Ludevik,no we are using libgdx as a game engine and embedded box2d in libgdx for physics

Comment: @Ludevik, as you have mentioned scene2D, i have gone through that and got an idea on how to accomplish my requirement.I have tried it, but the only problem is scene2D is rendered by using local-coordinates, but the ball which iam moving has the positions in the form of vector.Is there any way for this. I have tried with the method like this  image.toLocalCoordinates(new Vector2(x,y)); , but din't succeed,is there any way of doing this.

Comment: If you want to use scene2d from libgdx, then you use Stage - it has OrthographicCamera. You create ball Actor and move that actor using box2d. You override render() method in your ball actor and store its coordinates into list and render stored coordinates. Checkout this example on how to render box2d bodies: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Box2DDebugRenderer.java

Comment: yes i have tried this,Image img=new Image("image",texture);  @Ludevik img.x=10; img.y=10; stage.addActor(img); the coordinates which iam storing in list are stored inthe form of Vector, but the actor takes the axis as y-axis pointing upword. So, i can't able to draw the actor at the position where i want.

Comment: @Ludevik thank you so much for your reply.And i have solved this problem without using scene2D.I have given the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this by storing all the co-ordinates of my ball in a list. And drawn a   texture using SpriteBatch. But, one thing while storing the co-ordinates don't store a vector2   directly in a list, better store x and y positions as a string and then use split() method to   separate x and y axis. Because, Vector2 gets updated automatically.